# Creating node library in Webpack 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, configuration, dependencies

I'm trying to create node library using webpack and babel so that I can use ES2017. Everything works properly but the problem is a size of the output file which is huge comparing to the original file size. My test library is really simple and as the only dependency has `mongodb` package. Here is entire code of the library:

```
import crypto from "crypto";
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

let client = null;
let db = null;

/**
 * Connects to database using info defined in environment variables (MONGO_URL,
 * MONGO_DATABASE, MONGO_SSL, MONGO_SSL_VALIDATE).
 *
 * @async
 * @function connect
 */
const connect = async () => {
  if (!client) {
    // Connect to MongoDB server.
    client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
      ssl: process.env.MONGO_SSL || false,
      sslValidate: process.env.MONGO_SSL_VALIDATE || false
    });
    // Get database.
    db = client.db(process.env.MONGO_DATABASE);
  }
};

/**
 * Disconnects from database.
 *
 * @async
 * @function disconnect
 */
const disconnect = async () => {
  if (client) {
    await client.close();
    client = null;
    db = null;
  }
};

/**
 * Disconnects from database.
 *
 * @function getDatabase
 * @return {Db} MongoDB instance of the Db class.
 */
const getDatabase = () => {
  if (!client) {
    throw new Error("Not connected to database");
  }
  return db;
};

/**
 * Gets collection.
 *
 * @function getCollection
 * @return {Collection<TSchema>} MongoDB instance of the Collection class.
 */
const getCollection = collectionName => {
  if (!client) {
    throw new Error("Not connected to database");
  }
  // Get collection.
  return db.collection(collectionName);
};

/**
 * Generates Mongo ID string compatible with Meteor Mongo IDs.
 *
 * @function generateId
 * @param {number} charsCount - Length of the Mongo ID string.
 * @return {string} Mongo ID string compatible with Meteor Mongo ID.
 */
const generateId = (charsCount = 17) => {
  const CHARS = "23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  const digits = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < charsCount; i++) {
    let bytes;
    try {
      bytes = crypto.randomBytes(4);
    } catch (e) {
      bytes = crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(4);
    }
    const hexString = bytes.toString("hex").substring(0, 8);
    const fraction = parseInt(hexString, 16) * 2.3283064365386963e-10;
    const index = Math.floor(fraction * CHARS.length);
    digits[i] = CHARS.substr(index, 1);
  }
  return digits.join("");
};

export { connect, disconnect, getDatabase, getCollection, generateId };
```

And here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require("path");
const paths = require("../lib/paths");

const externals = Object.keys(
  require(path.resolve(paths.pkg, "package.json")).dependencies || {}
);

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  entry: path.resolve(paths.src, "index.js"),
  output: {
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
    path: paths.dist,
    filename: "index.js"
  },
  node: {
    __filename: true,
    __dirname: true
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  target: "node",
  externals: externals,
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: {
          loader: paths.loaders.babel,
          options: {
            plugins: [
              paths.plugins.proposalClassProperties,
              paths.plugins.proposalObjectRestSpread,
              paths.plugins.transformRuntime
            ],
            presets: [[paths.presets.env, { targets: { node: "6.10" } }]]
          }
        },
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The output file is 19 KB in size... It contains a lot of I guess polyfills which are not necessary. Why the hell webpack is including them in the output file even when I told it that I'm creating library.

In the `.map` file I can see that there are things like: `"webpack:///./node_modules/core-js/library/modules/_has.js"` or `"webpack:///./node_modules/@babel/runtime/core-js/promise.js"`

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want to use webpack if your library is consumed in a Node environment. Simply running all files through babel is probably sufficient.

*Webpack is intended to transform a dependency tree in any module syntax into a single bundle for use in a web browser.*

In your case the only objective is to transpile one language level to another, which is exactly what babel does. The [babel docs](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/) provide enough information on how to use the babel-cli to transpile your code.

Comment: Yep, I know about it. I used to use just Babel but it wasn't working in the use case I have. Actually, I'm just presenting only a simple piece of a bigger tool I'm creating. I'm creating a tool for creating node packages. I'm creating a lot of packages for a project and I'm tired of configuring each package with webpack and it's hard to keep configuration up to date. I needed webpack to have more control over the build process.

Comment: Could you show a babel config example, please? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a problem. The big file size is caused by `babel-plugin-transpile-runtime`. Actually, instead of requiring features from the plugin it just puts all the code inside the file. I don't know why it's doing it. So as I know what's causing it, I still don't know how to fix it.